# Mips Assembly find the address of the longest word in string

Tags: string, assembly, byte, mips

I am new to Mips Assembly programming. I have this project:

Firstly, We have to load the address of a given string into a register. This string contains a sentence (an array of characters) and words are seperated with space. Then we have to find the length of each word and compare their length with the lengths of others words. Finally we need to find the word with the longest length and print the address of its first letter.

For example, if the string is:

```
string: .asciiz "This is a wonderful day"
```

we must return the address, which w is stored.

So far I've written this:

```
.globl main
.text
    main:
      la $a0, string        #Load the address of the string to $a0
      addu $v1, $0, $a0     #Initialize the address of the longest word to v1

    exit:                   #Exiting the program
      addiu $v0, $zero, 10  
      syscall

.data
string: .asciiz "This is a wonderful day"
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

The implementation in java could be something like this:

```
int i = 0;
int Counter1 = 0;
int Counter2 = 0;
int address1 = getTheAddressOfCharacter(string[i]); //get the address of     the first letter of the string.
while(string[i] != ' ')  //find the length of the 1st word and store it in counter1.
{
    Counter1 += 1;
    i += 1;
}

int address2 = getTheAddressOfCharacter(string[i]); //get the address of     the second letter of the string.
while(string[i] != '\0')
{
    if(string[i] != ' ')
    {
        if(Counter2 == 0)
            address2 = getTheAddressOfCharacter(string[i]);
        Counter2 += 1;
     }
    else
    {
        if(Counter2 > Counter1) 
        {
            address1 = address2;
            Counter1 = Counter2;
        }
        Counter2 = 0;
    }
    i += 1;
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem? Design some algorithm first, write that in comments into code. After you will have algorithm in comments, keep refining them, until all comments describe only some simple operations, and until you verify that such algorithm works correctly (also for different inputs, like empty string, single word, only space in input, etc..). After that you can write instructions, which will implement that.

Comment: That "in java" would not work correctly (and I don't mean the non-java thing like "getAddress", I mean it's logic). You fail to update `address2` at proper times. It would also crash for empty string input. It would return address of space for string of single space, maybe it would be more correct to display "no word found". While addressing the `address2` update mechanism, keep in mind a mischievous tester would add also double-triple space between words, or space end of string (but generally not a bad try, also the used operations resemble assembly instructions enough).

Comment: maybe leave the Java, and consider "string[i]" equivalent to "value at address" (as that's simple to do in assembly), so you don't need to work with both addresses and indexes, you can use one of them for everything in this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edits are showing good progress...

Some more ideas for you to explore:

I would init maxLength to `0` and leave address unassigned (result output must respect this and display "no word found" when (0 == maxLength), to not touch undefined memory).

Then you don't need to have two separate loops to track first/other words separately, you can treat the first word already as any other, if it is longer than 0 characters, it will set up current [maxLength, maxWordAdr] pair to correct values. The single loop logic will be still quite complex to resolve all those trimmings/etc, but your "in java" for Counter2 looks quite promising, and you will avoid fixing the Counter1 loop to the same level.

Rename the variables to better describe their purpose (var1/var2/var3 is hard to read)... I know this is lost in the asm instruction themselves, using only rX registers, but that's just one more reason to keep all comments clear, lean, up-to-date and local to the code which they describe.

When I'm writing my own ASM sources, I usually have either 1-2 line big comments ahead of group instructions doing single task, or even small hint-comments on particular instruction line, so you should end with at least 20+% of source being comments.

After such clean-up just try to run in head that algorithm for 2-3 basic test input strings, and if everything fits, start writing the asm for it, should be quite straightforward. When unsure, use the debugger to verify the instructions do exactly what you expected.